# Adding elements through code in a grid - WP

Tags: c#, xaml, button, windows-phone-8, grid

I'm trying to do something which is as simple as adding elements to a 6x7 grid through code behind. The grid is defined in xaml as following

```
        <Grid x:Name="CalendarGrid" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>               

        </Grid>
```

I have a function called InitializeCalendar which would populate the grid with buttons. Somehow I cant figure out how to specify row and column to which I want to add the button. How to I reference the row and column of CalendarGrid?

```
    void InitializeCalendar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; i < 7; j++)
            {
                butArray[i + 1, j + 1] = new Button();
                //CalendarGrid. I cant find function to specify the row and button
            }
        }
    }
```

I found that there is a property called ColumnProperty.

```
butArray[i + 1, j + 1].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
```

But then there are so many Grids in my page. How do I reference the CalendarGrid? Any solutions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Grid.SetRow` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setrow.aspx)) and `Grid.SetColumn` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumn.aspx)) methods:

```
void InitializeCalendar()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            butArray[i, j] = new Button();
            butArray[i, j].Content = (i).ToString() + (j).ToString();                 
            CalendarGrid.Children.Add(butArray[i, j]);
            Grid.SetRow(butArray[i, j], i);
            Grid.SetColumn(butArray[i, j], j);                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more thing, there is a padding for each cell. I want the button to fill the cell. How do I do that?

Comment: @alfah probably you have global style for button. Can you show me screen shot with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the button to the CalendarGrid. Try the following way:

```
CalendarGrid.Children.Add(butArray[i + 1, j + 1]);
butArray[i + 1, j + 1].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columnNumber);
butArray[i + 1, j + 1].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, rowNumber);
```